# Access JFrame from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How can I access JFrame from another class?
I am trying to add a JLabel (jlabel_title) to my JFrame (frame).

```
public class Frame_Main
{
    public static void createWindow()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,250));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame_Menu frame_menu = new Frame_Menu();
        frame.setMenuBar(frame_menu.getMenubar());
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        createTitle();
    }

    public static void createTitle()
    {
        //IF abfrage integrierieren ob jlabel leer ist
        JLabel jlabel_title = new JLabel("test");
        jlabel_title.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        jlabel_title.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 20));
        jlabel_title.setVisible(true);
```

Error shows up here:

```
        Frame_Main.createWindow(frame).add(jlabel_title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: How `Frame_Main.createWindow(frame) ` is a valid statement ? It will not compile as there is no such method with a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, do not use static methods unless really required (there is no reason to do so here).

Then, add the `JFrame` as a member to your class - it is then accessible from the class's methods:

```
public class Frame_Main {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public void createWindow() {
    // ...
    }


    public void createTitle() {
    // ...
        frame.add(jlabel_title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

In the calling code, you then need to create an instance of your `Frame_Main` class and call the `createWindow()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Frame_Main mainWindow = new Frame_Main();
           mainWindow.createWindow();
        }
    });
}
```

(you might change `createWindow()` into something like `initializeWindow()` since that is what the method actually does)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but isnt it necessary to make createWindow() and createTitle() a static methode, when you call them afterwards in your public static void main with the command 'Frame_Main.createWindow();'?
Edit: Didnt noticed that you added a calling code, gonna try it out now

Comment: No, since you are creating a new instance of the class. `main` is only static by convention, since the JVM needs to have some entry point